# Куда обращается gradle за org.springframework.boot

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

При загрузке проекта возникает сообщение

> Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'] was
>   not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE')
>     Searched in the following repositories:
>     Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому http-адресу пытается обратиться gradle для поиска org.springframework.boot? Я правильно понимаю, что по адресу https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot?

П.С.: Сам проект сформирован как пустой на сервисе https://start.spring.io/

Вот build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

27.01.2020:

Вывод команды gradle build --scan:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Auto-applied by using --scan

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.build-scan', version: '2.2.1', artifact: 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:2.2.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:2.2.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Поставил gradle отдельно, добавил путь к его папке bin в path. Проверил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот результат gradle build --debug (часть)

```
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file 'C:\Users\***\Desktop\tstSpring\tstSpring\build.gradle' line: 10
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.12.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
16:08:59.178 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.12.RELEASE')
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Searched in the following repositories:
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     Gradle Central Plugin Repository
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
16:08:59.179 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

28 01 2020:

Запустил из папки проекта bootrun

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

29 01 2020

Запустил gradlew bootrun. Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А может взять какой-нибудь [фиддлер](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) и попробовать отследить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если запустить билдер с полной трассировкой `gradle build --scan` то в отчёте о разрешении зависимостей фигурирует адрес `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/`

```
Maven Central
Url https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
Dependencies
    ...
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starters:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.2.4.RELEASE
    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.2.4.RELEASE
    ...
Configurations
```

**добавлено 29.01.2020**

В учебных учреждениях часто практикуется подключение к Интернету через прокси, но ни `gradle`, ни `gradle wrapper` не умеют самостоятельно определять настройки прокси-сервера. Это можно исправить добавив в файл настроек `gradle.properties` (он должен находиться в домашней директории пользователя в подкаталоге `.gradle`) следующие строки:

для протокола HTTP

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

для протокола HTTPS

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Конкретные значения параметров, разумеется, будут другими. Взято из [документации](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) `gradle`.

**добавлено 28.01.2020**

Для `Windows` источником проблемы может быть встроенный `брандмауэр защитника Windows`, который блокирует доступ в Интернет всем программам, кроме указанных в списке. Посмотреть список разрешенных программ можно либо через панель управления `(Панель управления/Система и безопасность/Брандмауэр Защитника Windows/Разрешенные программы)`, либо через `Параметры/Безопасность Windows/Брандмауэр и защита сети/Разрешить работу с приложением через брандмауэр`.

[image: исключения брандмауэра]

Прежде всего нас интересуют строки

- IntelliJ IDEA
- Java(TM) Platform SE binary
- OpenJDK Platform binary (добавлено для полноты списка)

Отсутствие самой строки, либо галочки, означает блокировку сетевых функций программы. Вносить изменения можно только после нажатия кнопки `Изменить параметры`, добавить программу можно кнопкой `Разрешить другое приложение...` и указав путь к исполняемому файлу (например `C:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe`).

Comment: У меня другой вывод при этой команде, добавил в вопрос.Получается, что нет плагина, который делает scan?

Comment: Напрямую адрес, указанный в вашем сообщении, доступен.

Comment: Очистка `~\.gradle\caches` не помогает?

Comment: Нет. Удалил все в папке <Пользователь>\.gradle\caches, перезапустил Idea. Ничего не изменилось ((

Comment: Попробуйте без `Idea` - просто скачайте свежий Gradle в отдельную директорию, настройте в консоли к ней путь и дайте хоть какую-то отладочную информацию, если не `--scan` то хотя-бы `--debug`.

Comment: Скачал, скопировал в папку, прописал в Path, версия отобразилась. Idea по-прежнему не хочет работать. Добавил в задачу, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Может где-то в самой Idea надо указать путь?

Comment: Я надеялся на запуск билдера, версии `gradle` недостаточно. Пока не запустим проект из консоли, про `Idea` можно забыть. Рабочяя папка консоли должна быть `C:\Users\***\Desktop\tstSpring\tstSpring`, т.е. папка с `build.gradle`, команда `gradle bootRun` запускает всё без `Idea`. И ещё, на Windows довольно часто антивирус блокирует джаву, надо проверить.

Comment: Запустил из папки проекта bootrun - тот же результат (добавил в вопрос). Получается idea здесь не при чем? Антивирус не стоит локально. Java вызывается.

Comment: Меня всё-таки смущает версия `gradle 5.3`, запустите `gradle wrapper` командой `.\gradlew bootrun` - там должна быть более новая.

Comment: Попробовал, добавил в ответ. Не смог скачать. Что-то с сетью?

Comment: Брендмауэр отключен

Comment: Надо разбираться с сетью - тут может быть куча причин и в рамках ответа сделать это нереально. Причиной может быть и прокси-сервер и сбитый сетевой стек Windows и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо. Дождусь окончания конкурса, поблагодарю вас.

Comment: На всякий пожарный добавил про прокси-сервер (для студентов это актуально)

Comment: Да, к сожалению, у меня тоже там все правильно (( Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в начало

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Это позволит искать твой плагин в центральном репозитории maven.

Обрати внимание, что корневая секция

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

предназначена для `dependencies`, но не для `plugins`

Comment: Добавил в самое начало, перед plugins, но ситуация не изменилась. Я подозреваю что это связано с доступом к репозиториями, поэтому и хотел напрямую проверить путь по которому gradle должен подтягивать зависимости.